# How to chane the src of an image with delays in javascript using an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have had two problems so far, setting delays for each of the images and the adresses of the images can sometimes be a different adress than what i wanted.
I am making this on a django template, so I have this as my array:

```
var data = ["{% static 'kp1.png' %}", "{% static 'kp2.png' %}", "{% static 'kp3.png' %}", "{% static 'kp4.png' %}", "{% static 'kp5.png' %}", "{% static 'kp6.png' %}", "{% static 'kp7.png' %}", "{% static 'kp8.png' %}", "{% static 'kp9.png' %}", "{% static 'kp10.png' %}", "{% static 'kp11.png' %}", "{% static 'kp12.png' %}", "{% static 'kp13.png' %}", "{% static 'kp14.png' %}", "{% static 'kp15.png' %}", "{% static 'kp16.png' %}", "{% static 'kp17.png' %}", "{% static 'kp18.png' %}", "{% static 'kp19.png' %}", "{% static 'kp20.png' %}", "{% static 'kp21.png' %}", "{% static 'kp22.png' %}", "{% static 'kp23.png' %}", "{% static 'kp24.png' %}"]
```

Here is my html image and button

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AGNmyxb_rW-rOVKfMwOH50Wy10CcnROIFLMmjfEcvwGU8g=k-s48" id="kp_img">
<button id="kp_button" onclick="kp_animation()">click me</button>
```

```
And if this is what my javascript looks like

function kp_animation(){
  for(x in data){
    setTimout(() => {
     document.getElementById("kp_img").src = "kp" + x + ".png";
    },1000)
  }
}
```

The adress i am trying to acsess is http://website/static/kpX.png

But if i am in this domain http://website/domain1/domain2 then it gives me this: http://website/domain1/domain2/static/kpX.png

What is also happening is i am getting the first delay than it jumps to kp24.png and doesn't do any of the other delays

I would really apreciate it if someone could help

Comment: `setTimeout` != `setInterval`. Read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: you are calling setTimeout in a loop so all the src change would be done almost at the same time after 1 sec. you could set delay as n*1000 where n being the iteration count and also use a self invoking function to pass x as parameter for each src value setting.

Comment: The part *"the adresses of the images can sometimes be a different adress than what i wanted"* is not clear. Is the folder path `"/static/"` or not?

Comment: To avoid affecting a global `x`, use `for(let x in data)` instead of `for(x in data)`

Comment: Also, all your iterations are currently set to be "1000ms from the time of the call", not "1000ms from each other". So there is indeed "no other delays" in your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the delays else all setTimeout be executed almost at the same time and also without making x a local variable for each setTimeout, x will refer to the last value always so a self invoking function would help.

```
var counter = 0;
for (x in data) {
  ((x) => {
    setTimout(() => {
      document.getElementById("kp_img").src = "kp" + x + ".png";
    }, 1000 * counter++)
  })(x)
}
```

Additionally, make sure the image urls allow CORS to be loaded in a different site.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to help you with getting the paths to your images (someone with a fresh memory on Django might help here), but related to your button and the **interval** - ...use setInterval instead of setTimeout.

Also, to loop your images back to the beginning, don't forget about the modulo operator `%` - it'll help you to reset the iterating images index back to `0`

Also, don't use HTML inline `on*` Event handlers. Use addEventListener() instead.

```js
const elKpButton = document.querySelector("#kp_button");
const elKpImg = document.querySelector("#kp_img");

const staticPath = "/static/"; // Or whatever the path to static assets
const data = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"]; // populate however you need to
const imagesTotal = data.length;
let imageIndex = 0; // Start from image index 0
let imagesInterval = null;


elKpButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (imagesInterval) {
    clearInterval(imagesInterval); // Clear interval
    imagesInterval = null;         // Reset interval ID
  } else {
   imagesInterval = setInterval(() => {
     elKpImg.src = staticPath + data[imageIndex]; // set new image source
     imageIndex += 1;           // increment
     imageIndex %= imagesTotal; // loop-back to 0
   }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
img::after { content: attr(src); }
```

```html
<button id="kp_button">click me</button>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AGNmyxb_rW-rOVKfMwOH50Wy10CcnROIFLMmjfEcvwGU8g=k-s48" id="kp_img">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use async/await for Promise to achieve :**

```js
async function kp_animation(){
  for(let x in data){
    await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
     document.getElementById("kp_img").src = "kp" + x + ".png";
     //to fullfill promise
     resolve(true);
    },1000)
    })
  }
}

kp_animation();
```